Positive, Real Roots of Bivariate Polynomial
I have a question regarding lemma 3.1 in this paper. The lemma in question is as follows

Consider the function $f(x, \lambda) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ where $a > 0$ is
fixed but for which the coefficients $b$, $c$ and $d$ are each continuous functions of some parameter $\lambda$ where, in particular, $d$ is a strictly decreasing function of $\lambda$. Suppose that, for some $\lambda = \lambda_d > 0$, we have $c(\lambda_d) < 0$ and $d(\lambda_d) = 0$. Then there exists some $\lambda = \lambda_1 > 0$ (where $d(\lambda_1) > 0$) such that $f(x, \lambda) = 0$ has two positive real roots for all $d$ in $(0, d(\lambda_1))$.

I am interested in understanding under which conditions we can find an explicit form for $\lambda_1$, particularly when the coefficients of $f$ are defined in terms of parameters (and are quite convoluted). Any hints or directions would be greatly appreciated.
